# Fastest method to find a fileName from a pattern in nio or file object in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a location where I have stored 1 million files. I want to get all the files in a list and find all the files that contain a word in the file name from that list. The only thing important here is that the performance should be very good. All the things should happen very quickly hence I am looking at the quickest method for this. I am confused whether java tradition file object should be used or NIO should be used. I have tried the file object as follows:

```
    String[] fileList = null;
    String fileNamePart = "somepartoffileName";
      try{
        File rootFolder = new File(dir);
        if(rootFolder.isDirectory()){
            fileList = rootFolder.list();

       }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Not a valid directory "+dir);
    }

    String[] listFiles = Arrays.stream(fileList).filter(s -> 
    s.contains(FileNamePart)).toArray(String []::new);
```

Is there any faster way to achieve this? I dont mind using the file array or something from nio but my performance should be faster. Also the pattern to match can be from 1 to 1000. so there can be wither one string to match or that string can contain  1000 comma separated values

Comment: You should read the source of the API's you use to get a better idea of what they do. File.list() loads your million Strings into an internal ArrayList. Copies all entries from it to another million entry String array. Then you filter through that and copy the matcing entries to a third array. I odn't see how you could find a worse performing API.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated, even by pre-Java 8 standards. The [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list--) does not mention any exceptions thrown for invalid directories (the method will return `null` instead), so there’s no reason to add this exception handling. Further, the method will return `null` if the file is not a directory, so the `rootFolder.isDirectory()` test is obsolete as well.

So, getting an unfiltered list, is as simple as

```
File rootFolder = new File(dir);
String[] fileList = rootFolder.list();
```

and it’s easy to add a filter, now calling [`File.list(FilenameFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list-java.io.FilenameFilter-), using Java 8 features:

```
File rootFolder = new File(dir);
String[] fileList = rootFolder.list((p, n) -> n.contains(fileNamePart));
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is to not create the list of all files. Traditionally one could use a FileNameFilter, but with the new streams:

```
Path path = Paths.get(dir);
String[] listFiles = Files.list(path)
    .map(p -> p.getFileName().toString())
    .filter(s -> s.contains(FileNamePart)).toArray(String []::new);
```

A List seems more versatile:

```
List<String> listFiles = Files.list(path)
    .map(p -> p.getFileName().toString())
    .filter(s -> s.contains(FileNamePart))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks to @jaspreet mentioning subdirectories not wanted (I had `.walk` instead of `.list`).

Comment: I think instead of walk method it should be Files.list() method as he doesn't wants to find files inside the directory also.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) from [NIO2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). Oracle have a detailed [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) of walking the file tree in various cases:

```
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;

// The file we are looking for.
Path lookingFor = ...;

public FileVisitResult
    visitFile(Path file,
        BasicFileAttributes attr) {
    if (file.getFileName().equals(lookingFor)) {
        System.out.println("Located file: " + file);
        return TERMINATE;
    }
    return CONTINUE;
}
```

You don't need to store the whole list in memory for that.